# Javascript - accessing an object with duplicate names

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, object

I have an XML file that I read in to a Javascript object.  This is called jsonXML.  I can see the object in its entirety in the console when I log it. It is a pretty complex object with a lot of layers and duplication.

I need to access some of these duplicate objects but I can't seem to drill down into the specifics that I need.  The problem I'm having is the duplicate objects.

Here's the structure of the JS object:

1. **ProfileGroup:**

   1. **File:** (there are 85 "File Objects" I need to access)

      2. 0: (I think in the tree this is the array index of the *File*)

         1. **Profile:**

            1. **WayPt:** (there are two "WayPt" objects for each file I need to access both)
            2. 0: (I think in the tree this is the array index of the *WayPt*)

               1. distance
               2. localCoords
         2. **WayPt:**

            1. 1: (I think in the tree this is the array index of the *WayPt*)

               1. distance
               2. localCoords

I was using this just to try and access the objects:

```
console.log(jsonXML.ProfileGroup.File.Profile.WayPt);
```

I can get the array of files with `console.log(jsonXML.ProfileGroup.File);` 
But I can't get individual "File" objects or anything else past that.

Any info on this issue would be helpful. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is some stingified JSON for those who would like to see it:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
"xmlns": "www.geophysical.com/DZX/1.02",
"GlobalProperties": {
    "verticalUnit": "cm",
    "horizontalUnit": "m",
    "dielectric": "1.8000000",
    "readOnly": "0",
    "unitsPerMark": "100.0000000",
    "unitsPerScan": "0.0200000"
},
"Macro": {
    "state": "0",
    "Process": [
        {
            "state": "0",
            "BinaryData": "0&``!```$$`!C``H``````\"`@\n"
        },
        {
            "state": "0",
            "BinaryData": "L+``!```$)`!-`C,ST[\\`````````````A$$````````````````````````@\n"
        },
        {
            "state": "0",
            "BinaryData": "ME@`!```$C@`[`P````!!``\"X00``A$(`````````````````````````````\nM````````````````````````````````@$H``,A\"``#_`P``````````````\nM````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````\n/````````````````````\n"
        },
        {
            "state": "0",
            "BinaryData": "M2``!```$0``$```````#```````````````````````@`V0```#_`P``````\n;````````````````````````````````````\n"
        },
        {
            "state": "0",
            "BinaryData": "0$``!```$\"``G`0```````\"`@\n"
        }
    ]
},
"ProfileGroup": {
    "scanRange": "0,88815",
    "Radan3D": {
        "localMinCoords": "-0.5000000,0.0000000,0.0000000",
        "localMaxCoords": "18.0000000,25.0000000,0.0000000",
        "globalMinCoords": "0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000",
        "globalMaxCoords": "0.0000000,0.0000000,0.0000000",
        "localRotationAngle": "0.0000000",
        "displayXDirProfs": "1",
        "displayYDirProfs": "1",
        "displayOtherDirProfs": "0",
        "hide": "0",
        "localGain": "0.0000000",
        "displayOrder": "0",
        "flipDataInVertDir": "0",
        "flipDataInHorizDir": "0"
    },
    "File": [
        {
            "scanRange": "0,887",
            "name": "HARMONY   __050.DZT",
            "Profile": {
                "scanRange": "0,887",
                "Comment": {
                    "scan": "0",
                    "description": "Data Collection Notes: "
                },
                "WayPt": [
                    {
                        "scan": "0",
                        "mark": "User",
                        "name": "Mark2",
                        "distance": "0.0000000",
                        "localCoords": "0.0000000,0.5000000,0.0000000"
                    },
                    {
                        "scan": "887",
                        "distance": "18",
                        "localCoords": "18,0.5000000,0.0000000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "scanRange": "888,1785",
            "name": "HARMONY   __051.DZT",
            "Profile": {
                "scanRange": "888,1785",
                "Comment": {
                    "scan": "888",
                    "description": "Data Collection Notes: "
                },
                "WayPt": [
                    {
                        "scan": "888",
                        "mark": "User",
                        "name": "Mark2",
                        "distance": "0.0000000",
                        "localCoords": "18.0000000,0.5208333,0.0000000"
                    },
                    {
                        "scan": "1785",
                        "distance": "17.9400000",
                        "localCoords": "0.0600000,0.5208333,0.0000000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "scanRange": "1786,2681",
            "name": "HARMONY   __052.DZT",
            "Profile": {
                "scanRange": "1786,2681",
                "Comment": {
                    "scan": "1786",
                    "description": "Data Collection Notes: "
                },
                "WayPt": [
                    {
                        "scan": "1786",
                        "mark": "User",
                        "name": "Mark2",
                        "distance": "0.0000000",
                        "localCoords": "-0.5000000,1.0416667,0.0000000"
                    },
                    {
                        "scan": "2681",
                        "distance": "17.9000000",
                        "localCoords": "17.4000000,1.0416667,0.0000000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "scanRange": "2682,3574",
            "name": "HARMONY   __053.DZT",
            "Profile": {
                "scanRange": "2682,3574",
                "Comment": {
                    "scan": "2682",
                    "description": "Data Collection Notes: "
                },
                "WayPt": [
                    {
                        "scan": "2682",
                        "mark": "User",
                        "name": "Mark2",
                        "distance": "0.0000000",
                        "localCoords": "18.0000000,1.5625000,0.0000000"
                    },
                    {
                        "scan": "3574",
                        "distance": "17.8400000",
                        "localCoords": "0.1600000,1.5625000,0.0000000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "scanRange": "3575,4470",
            "name": "HARMONY   __054.DZT",
            "Profile": {
                "scanRange": "3575,4470",
                "Comment": {
                    "scan": "3575",
                    "description": "Data Collection Notes: "
                },
                "WayPt": [
                    {
                        "scan": "3575",
                        "mark": "User",
                        "name": "Mark2",
                        "distance": "0.0000000",
                        "localCoords": "-0.5000000,2.0833333,0.0000000"
                    },
                    {
                        "scan": "4470",
                        "distance": "17.9000000",
                        "localCoords": "17.4000000,2.0833333,0.0000000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "scanRange": "4471,5370",
            "name": "HARMONY   __055.DZT",
            "Profile": {
                "scanRange": "4471,5370",
                "Comment": {
                    "scan": "4471",
                    "description": "Data Collection Notes: "
                },
                "WayPt": [
                    {
                        "scan": "4471",
                        "mark": "User",
                        "name": "Mark2",
                        "distance": "0.0000000",
                        "localCoords": "18.0000000,2.6041667,0.0000000"
                    },
                    {
                        "scan": "5370",
                        "distance": "17.9800000",
                        "localCoords": "0.0200000,2.6041667,0.0000000"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

}

The file is very long so I truncated it at the end of a File.

Comment: Could you please show us the actual JSON not a "structure" list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually looked around and figured out how to do this.  I found it under a different topic but figured that I might help anyone else with this specific question.

To get to these multiple array items, you have to put in the index like this:

```
console.log(jsonXML.ProfileGroup.File["0"].Profile.WayPt["0"].distance);
```

When iterating through the object, you can use this:

```
files=[];  //array of file names
daters=[];  //final array of arrays
tempVal =[];  //temporary array
subArray=[];  //temporary array of sub values
var filz = jsonXML.ProfileGroup.File.length;
//depending on how many files there are, find out how many
for (i=0;i<filz;i++)
{
  //add each file name to an array called 'files'
  files.push(jsonXML.ProfileGroup.File[i].name);
  //since in my example there are two objects called WayPt
  for (j=0; j<2; j++)
  {
    //I use an array here to make it easy to combine into the other array
    tempVal.push(jsonXML.ProfileGroup.File[i].Profile.WayPt[j].distance);
    //since I have a string of comma separated values, make an array of these
    subArray = jsonXML.ProfileGroup.File[i].Profile.WayPt[j].localCoords.split(',');
    //combine the two above arrays
    arrayNew = tempVal.concat(subArray)
    push this array into the final array to use later
    daters.push(arrayNew);
    //reset the temporary values otherwise they will keep getting larger
    tempVal=[];
    arrayNew=[];
    subArray=[]; 
  }
}
```

This is how you drill down into the object when there are multiple entries in a named field.

Hope this helps anyone else!